# With a bash script that utilizes system commands; how would you have it input when the COMMAND asks you for something?

Tags: linux, bash, input, terminal, command

So suppose a normal command run in terminal goes like this....

```
user$ thecommand
Please enter your first name:
>
```

and then waits for your to type your name... straightforward, but if in a bash script I try and do something like:

```
#! /bin/bash
 echo "What is your name?"
     read name
 thecommand
```

how would I have THE SCRIPT enter "$name" in response to "thecommand" instead of having the user manually input it themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add input by pipe like this:

```
echo yourname | ./yourscript
```

for more inputs you can use `printf`

```
printf "input1\ninput2" | ./yourscript
```

where `\n` means new line and it will be used like new input.

Comment: thanks for the response! Question though; what if ./myscript asks for a second and third ect.... input(s) afterwards?

Comment: answer adapted for your additional question

Answer (score 0):

Run your script like:

**./yourscript.sh < file.txt**

where file.txt will contain the name.

now your script will look for name from the file(file.txt), in file.txt you can type the names which will act as input for read command.
**read** command reads on line at a time so if u have more than on **read** command in your script you should have multiple lines in file.txt file

Comment: I like the look of this method!

So would it work if I had ./myscript write a few lines to a file.txt, and then ran:

user$ thecommand < file.txt ??

Answer (score 0):

For complicated cases, for example if your input depends on the output of your command, you may write an "expect" script.

To see how it works you can auto-generate such script interactively

`$ autoexpect thecommand`

And then run it

`$ expect -f script.exp`